# Swift UILabels in a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a UIView inside of a table view cell. I would like to display text in that table view. heres what i have so far in the UIView.swift file.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CardView: UIView {
    var contact: Contact?

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 2

    @IBInspectable var shadowOffsetWidth: Int = 0
    @IBInspectable var shadowOffsetHeight: Int = 0


    @IBOutlet weak private var nameLabel: UILabel!{
       self.nameLabel.text = "Name: \(contact!.name)"
    }



    override func layoutSubviews() {
        layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)

        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2).CGColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shadowOffsetWidth, height: shadowOffsetHeight);
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
        layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath
    }
}
```

There is an error with the label not being able to produce the text. Any Help will be awesome!

Comment: what error you are facing?

Comment: ` @IBOutlet weak private var nameLabel: UILabel!{
       self.nameLabel.text = "Name: \(contact!.name)"
    }' It says its incorrect. So basically I'm wondering what is the correct way for display text?

Comment: How do you insert `CardView` in `UITableViewCell`? Are you using Storyboard or Programatically? Might be you have not connected `IBOutlets`.

Comment: When you define `nameLabel` you don't have value in `contact` object. you need to set value of your label explicitly to display.

Comment: I'm using Storyboard. The Label is connected to the `IBOutlet`. I just want the label to display any text. for example. `nameLabel.text = "Hello World!"`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to fix the code where you set text.

```
   @IBOutlet weak private var nameLabel: UILabel!{

       didSet{
          nameLabel.text = "Contact name goes here..."
      }
    }
```

So, whenever the nib loading logic sets up the label from your storyboard, the code inside **didSet** will be called and you can set whatever there.